# How to use AWS X-Ray with loopback + typescript

Tags: loopback4, aws-xray

I'm trying to integrate AWS X-Ray with a REST API server.

The server is developed with [loopback 4](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/index.html).

I have this in index.ts

```js
const app = new LoopbackApplication(options);

await app.boot();
await app.start();

const url = app.restServer.url;
console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);

return app;
```

### What did I try?

I tried to follow [this](https://extri.co/2017/03/10/integrating-aws-xray-with-loopback/) tutorial..

Added this segment in index.ts

```js
import * as xray from "aws-xray-sdk"

// ...

  const app = new LoopbackApplication(options);
  xray.express.openSegment("newseg");
  xray.express.closeSegment();
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  const url = app.restServer.url;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
  console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);

  return app;
```

The server works. But the x-ray trace is not shown in AWS. I also ran the local daemon, but it doesn't show any signs of receiving requests from the application.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be seeing any traces in X-Ray because the logic that starts up the server is not encapsulated within the segment that was created. I would suggest trying to close the segment before the return statement:

```
import * as xray from "aws-xray-sdk"

// ...

  const app = new LoopbackApplication(options);
  xray.express.openSegment("newseg");
  
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  const url = app.restServer.url;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
  console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);
    
  xray.express.closeSegment(); // close segment here instead

  return app;
```

The Express middleware is meant to be defined around **routes**, as shown in [our example code](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/express#capture-all-incoming-requests-to--and-directory), so I would also suggest following this guide for defining your routes in order to see traces in X-Ray! Our [documentation on tracing requests with the X-Ray SDK for Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-middleware.html) is also a very helpful resource.

Hope this helps, please let me know if you have any additional questions.